# In reactjs how do you get rid of the white outline around the page?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, next.js

Long story short I have simple starter project that is a single page form returned in an index.js that takes a ChatGPT prompt and uses a small server component (API) that retrieves a ChatGPT response and presents on the page.  I have some other controls on there but that's not important for this question.

My main page jsx is returned at the end of a Home() function (see code below). For the life of me, I cannot get rid of the white outline around the page no matter what I put in CSS or inline styling to the outer div element.  In Firefox and Chrome Inspector, it shows my root div element below the body element, both are the same size and slightly smaller than the page (hence the white box).  Above the body element, the outer html element is the only one that takes up the full page.  For example, the outer html element shows an element size of 1920x826 but the body and my div show only 1904x810, why don't they fill the page if set to no margin?

```
return (
  <div id="root" style={{margin: 0, backgroundColor: "#444654"}}>
  <Head>
    <title>OpenAI Quickstart</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/dog.png" />
  </Head>
  <main className={styles.main}>
    <img src="/dog.png" className={styles.icon} />
    <h3>OpenAI Portal</h3>
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <div className={styles.flexcontainer}>
        <div className={styles.leftpane}/>
        <div className={styles.middlepane}>
```

If I change the outer div tags for html>tags, like the below, it works!  I get edge to edge grey color like I want!  BUT ... I then get hydration errors because its "not expecting html in div", obviously having a problem with the html tag.  I cannot put an html {} in css because that throws errors that "it's not pure" (needs className).  I can't use a global.css for the same reason.  How can I accomplish getting rid of the white outline around my page and get edge to edge background color?

```
return (
  <html id="root" style={{margin: 0, backgroundColor: "#444654"}}>
  <Head>
    <title>OpenAI Quickstart</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/dog.png" />
  </Head>
  <main className={styles.main}>
    <img src="/dog.png" className={styles.icon} />
    <h3>OpenAI Portal</h3>
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <div className={styles.flexcontainer}>
        <div className={styles.leftpane}/>
        <div className={styles.middlepane}>
```

not sure if this is helpful but I think gives some config info from my package.json so you know what versions I am working with for next, node, and react:

```
{
  "name": "openai-quickstart-node",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "^13.3.1",
    "openai": "^3.2.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.6.0"
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I tried the above codes.  I am expecting to get edge to edge background color on my page and to not get a white outline or margin around the page.

Comment: Remove padding and margin from body

Comment: how do I do that?  I cannot put a body { } statement in .css because "it's not pure".  I also will get an error if I include the body tags in my return ( ... ).  I tried that hoping I could use inline styling.  also react appears to be inserting the root div below body.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not pure"? Usually there is a css reset added to the project that clear all browser-specific styling

Comment: I get an error adding any selector that is a not a class, for example adding a body { } to my index.module.css, I get:  Syntax error: Selector "body" is not pure (pure selectors must contain at least one local class or id)

Comment: You have to create a css file that is not a module and add it globally